# How to add an array to Firebase Firestore Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update the data in a document in Cloud Firestore with an array however whenever I try to do this I get an error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported type: __SwiftValue (found in field upvotes)'. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me understand what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this. Thanks. Code is below.

Code for updating array-

```
db.collection("forum").document(data[0].id!).setData(["upvotes": data[0].upvotes!.remove(at: data[0].upvotes!.firstIndex(of: MainView.username ?? "Anonymous")!)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass an array to Firestore to update an array property. What you're doing is passing an element of an array. The `remove(at:)` method, when used like this:

```
let removedElement = someArray.remove(at: someIndex)
```

will remove the element but return the value of that removed element; it doesn't return the updated array. You must first remove the element and then get the truncated array:

```
someArray.remove(at: someIndex)
let updated = someArray
```

Therefore, first remove, then update:

```
data[0].upvotes!.remove(at: data[0].upvotes!.firstIndex(of: MainView.username ?? "Anonymous")! // first remove
db.collection("forum").document(data[0].id!).setData([
    "upvotes": data[0].upvotes!) // then pass
])
```

However, I'd recommend reformatting the code because it doesn't read very well, IMO, and there is too much force unwrapping for my taste.